# How do I execute the contents of a field as a statement in mysql?

Tags: mysql, export

I've got a table I need to split into many .csv files with each file have a group of rows based on the contents of one of the columns.

I found this solution here: [Export Table Into Files Grouping By A Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933798/export-table-into-files-grouping-by-a-column), and got the query working just fine:

```
SELECT concat('SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE col1 = ''',
    col1, ''' INTO OUTFILE '''c:\result-', col1, '.txt'' ', 
    'FIELDS TERMINATED BY '','' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY ''"''',
    'LINES TERMINATED BY ''\n'';')
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY col1
```

However, when I execute this query, I get a single column of fields where each field has a select statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `col1` = 'value' INTO OUTFILE c:\results - value.csv  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY ' "' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

How do I execute each of those statements?

Comment: It appears your trying to execute a dynamic SQL statement.  Here's one prior answer which may help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591338/my-sql-dynamic-query-execute-and-get-ouput-into-a-variable-in-stored-procedure   or you can take this approach http://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=2793 using execute immediate syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use your temp-folder as middle-man, and save it as an sql-file there, and then run the file:

```
SELECT CONCAT('UPDATE a SET b = ', c, ' WHERE d = ', e, ';') AS query
   FROM x INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/update_a.sql';
SOURCE '/tmp/update_a.sql';
```

easy for one-time querys in the console, for use in software, you should use something better like @xQbert sugested

Comment: I didn't get what you were doing so I exported the output into a file, and then pasted the file into navicat..but I was just being stupid - I see what you're doing now, with the source line pulling the code back in. Nice!

Comment: source is nice for debuging to, usaly have a large sql in a text file, and then use source to try to run it